Object detection bounding boxes using yolov5s with onnx on ml.net
I know its been a while. I am using yolov5 with MAUI as well but in an ONNX form. I am having no trouble in getting the predictions but issue is with the bounding boxes they are way off.
my model has input of 1,3,640,640 and output 1,25200, 6. I am following this but no luck.
I want to get the bounding box over the detected object which right now is way off the actual object.
Any help would be much appreciated.
PS: the bounding box works perfectly with Yolov5Net nuget but it doesnt run on the app.

Please read [ask] before posting.  Your question doesn’t contain any meaningful details about what you are actually doing

hi @Jason, apologies. I want to get the bounding box from the predictions that I receive from the model. The bounding box that I get using the above example are off the actual detections.
